# Rails save model Attribute from another Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to change a value for a 'device' model from my User controller. Currently I get the device then set the value, but it isn't saving the value to the device. How do I get it to save? thanks

User controller.rb

```
      @device = @user.device
      @device.lastUpdated = Time(now)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save the changes to your database, you can use the save method. Try using @device.save after you update the attribute.

```
  @device = @user.device
  @device.lastUpdated = Time(now)
  if @device.save
    # do something when save is successful
  else
    # handle the case when it doesn't save properly
  end
```

Edit: Take a look at the list of [persistence methods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html) in the Rails documentation (i.e. these are methods that will write information to the database).